# CommandParameters in ContextMenu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I have a scenario where I have a WPF TreeView control that has an `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for its items. Now inside the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, I have a `Label` and the `Label` has a `ContextMenu` with a menuitem for `Delete`. The Delete menuitem is bound to a Command called `DeleteCommand` which is a part of the class that has been set as the `DataType` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Now, I want to pass the `TreeView` control in the `CommandParameters` of the ContextMenu's `Delete` menuitem's `DeleteCommand` so that I can handle the selection of the TreeViewItems on the deletion of the currently selected item.

But if I bind the `CommandParameters` as the `{Binding ElementName=TreeViewName}` or whatever for that matter, it is always null unless the binded element is a property in the `DataContext`.

Can anyone help me with a solution because I think, I have tried all the possible things such as RelativeSource and AncestorType etc but its always null. To me, it looks like either a limitation or a bug in the framework.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that the ContextMenu is at the root of its own visual tree, so any RelativeSource.FindAncestor bindings won't go past the ContextMenu.

One solution is to use the [PlacementTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx) property to set up a two-stage binding from your Label:

```
<Label Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={
    x:Type TreeView}}}">
    <Label.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{x:Static local:Commands.DeleteCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={
                RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Label.ContextMenu>
</Label>
```

This is quite hacky, however.  You're better off setting the [CommandTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandtarget.aspx) property of your MenuItem to the ContextMenu's PlacementTarget and having the command handler on your TreeView.  This means you won't have to pass the TreeView around.

Comment: Way easy: <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

Comment: @JoanComas: after trying all the others without success (nor understanding what it all meant with FindAncestors, etc), your Way easy way works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: @JoanComasFdz 's comment is really help. I can apply `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` simply.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit Item"
                   Command="{Binding EditItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding Path=UIElement.(views:DataGridView.SelectedItems), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
<ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WPF CommandParameter Binding Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257396/wpf-commandparameter-binding-problem). Maybe it can provide some pointers as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<MenuItem Header="..." 
          Command="{Binding Path=...}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
</MenuItem>
```

ContextMenu.PlacementTarget, is Label, where the menuitem is hosted. From Lavel, its parent Treeview is accessable.

Answer (score 0):

For each element in DataGrid

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit Item"
                   Command="{Binding EditItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
<ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding EventTreeViewViewItems}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">         
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />

                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
           
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <ui:BindingProxy x:Key="BindingProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
                <ContextMenu Name="test" x:Key="ContextMenuRouteIdNode">
                    <MenuItem Header="pan to" Command="{Binding Data.MenuCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="zoom to"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="select"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="alle grünen Events automatisch korrigieren"/>
                </ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuEventNode">
                    <MenuItem Header="pan to"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="zoom to"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="select"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Event automatisch korrigieren"/>
                </ContextMenu>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Name="TreeViewRouteIdNode" DataType="{x:Type ui:RouteIdNode}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding EventNode}" >
                    <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenuRouteIdNode}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RouteId}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:EventNode}">
                    <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenuEventNode}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0"  Foreground="{Binding Path=Brush}" Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >von:</Label>
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=From}" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >bis:</Label>
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=To}" />
                        </Grid>
  
                        
                       
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

This part did the job for me:

```
 <MenuItem Header="pan to" Command="{Binding Data.MenuCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```