# WPF treeview contextmenu command parameter

Tags: wpf, treeview, contextmenu, commandparameter

I have `TreeView` with `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. On `TreeView` I have `ContextMenu`

```
<TreeView Name="_packageTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding PackageExtendedList}" Behaviors:TreeViewInPlaceEditBehavior.IsEditable="True">
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu StaysOpen="true">
            <MenuItem Header="Добавить пакет" Height="20" Command="{Binding AddPackageCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_packageTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/Resources/ManualAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"></Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
   </TreeView.ContextMenu>
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">bla bla bla</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

As you can see, I bind `Command` to menu item. AddPackageCommand defined in ViewModell class as usually. Invoke command works fine, but I always have `null` in `CommandParameter`. I found some questions similar to my, but I don't understand solutions. For example:

[CommandParameters in ContextMenu in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504533/commandparameters-in-contextmenu-in-wpf)

Anyway it doesn't work for me :( What am I doing wrong?

**Updated**

That seems to be working, but it's all the same, I don't understand why `CommandParameter` doesn't work with `TreeView.Name`.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
```

for examplle, such a sample works fine

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PackageTreeItemChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_packageTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

What's the hell...

And anyway, I have `TreeView` object in `CommandParameter`, not `TreeViewItem`. I can get `SelectedItem` from `TreeView`, but how can I send exactly `TreeViewItem` as `CommandParameter`?

**to Sheridan**

Question was **WHY** this doesn't work.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_packageTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

And this works

```
CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
```

**WHY** sometimes I can use direct TreeView control name and sometimes I cannot.
As I understand, matter is different DataContext of `TreeView` control and `ContextMenu` because `ContextMenu` has its own VisualTree and it is not the part of `TreeView` `ViaualTree`.

Unfortunately, that approach **doesn't work** too, I have `null` again. I set TreeView.Tag, sure.

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={
            RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpen="true">
    <MenuItem Header="Добавить пакет" Height="20" Command="{Binding AddPackageCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_packageTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
             <Image Source="/Resources/ManualAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"></Image>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

This is the easiest way, but if I have SelectedItem property in ViewModel it has no sense bind it to `CommandParameter`, because I already have it in ViewModel.

```
 <MenuItem Header="Добавить пакет" Height="20" Command="{Binding AddPackageCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Resources/ManualAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"></Image>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: this stuff is so unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 2):

You showed us that you already have an answer... why on earth did you post yet another question on this same subject instead of simply following the example in the answer? It doesn't work for you, because you didn't copy the answer properly.

In your example post answer, the `Tag` property is set to the `TreeView` control that the menu is applied on, but you haven't done this.

Your next problem is that you have ignored this `Tag` property again in the `CommandParameter`... somehow, you have changed this from the correct answer:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}
```

to this in your question:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
```

All you needed to do was copy and paste it. All the same, you might have even more luck doing this:

```
<TreeView Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    Name="_packageTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding PackageExtendedList}" 
    Behaviors:TreeViewInPlaceEditBehavior.IsEditable="True">
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={
            RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpen="true">
            <MenuItem Header="Добавить пакет" Height="20" Command="{Binding AddPackageCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_packageTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/Resources/ManualAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"></Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
   </TreeView.ContextMenu>
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">bla bla bla</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Look at the `TreeView.Tag` property... this is set to its own `DataContext`, which means that whatever is set as the `DataContext` of the `TreeView` is now available in the `Tag` property object.

Next, look at the `ContextMenu.DataContext` property... this is set to the `Tag` property of the `PlacementTarget`, which is the control that the `ContextMenu` is applied to, or in this case, the `Treeview`.

If you haven't worked it out yet, this means that the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` is now set to the same object as the `DataContext` of the `TreeView`. If this is not what you want because your `Command` is on a different object, then just change the `Binding` path in the `Tag` property to point to wherever the object that had the `Command` is.

The last thing that you can do to make this simpler is to add a property to your view model/code behind that binds to the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property:

```
<TreeView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"... />
```

Then you can simply refer to this property for your `CommandParameter`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Добавить пакет" Height="20" Command="{Binding AddPackageCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Resources/ManualAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"></Image>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

This last part of course assumes that you have set your view model/code behind as the `Tag` property of the `TreeView`. If you still don't understand this, take a look at the [Context Menus in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html) page on WPF Tutorial.NET.

UPDATE >>>

I simply don't understand why you posted this question. First you said you couldn't do something, but then provided us with a link to a valid solution in another post. After trying to help you, you then say that it did work, but you don't know why... but then you correctly answered your own question again:

> As I understand, matter is different DataContext of TreeView control and ContextMenu because ContextMenu has its own VisualTree and it is not the part of TreeView ViaualTree.

As you said, the `ContextMenu` has its own visual tree. This means that it is not aware of controls, named or otherwise, in another visual tree. However, if the `ContextMenu.DataContext` is provided with an object such as the containing view, then it *can* be aware of controls in another visual tree (more specifically, the visual tree of the controls in the view).

This whole issue seems to be down to a lack of knowledge on your part about `Binding` in general and `Binding.Path` syntax more specifically. Please take a look at the following articles on MSDN for more help on this topic:

[Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)

[Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[RelativeSource MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)

So many people try to run with WPF before they can walk.

Comment: ---After trying to help you, you then say that it did work, but you don't know why. **No**, I say **YOUR** approach doesn't work. (I copied your code). Approach with binding DataContext to TreeView.Tag and so on. Approach which was suggested as answer in link that I posted. Even if I set ContextMenu.DataContext property as TreeView.Tag, even then I have null in `CommandParameter` :(

thx anyway.

Comment: Because *you* couldn't get my example to work does *not* mean that it does not work. It simply means that you don't understand it. If you took the time to learn `Binding` syntax like I suggested, then maybe you would understand it.

Comment: Did I say that you were stupid? No, I didn't. I simply said that you didn't understand it, which is clearly true. Can you not see how hard I tried to help you and how much I wrote? I'm not even going to reply to your last comments because *they* really are stupid.