# WPF Datagrid ContextMenu SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, contextmenu

I have the following problem.
I have a DataGrid with a ContextMenu. But when the Command is triggered the SelectedItem is always null. 
Any recommendations?

Thats my ContextMenu:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
           Header="open file" />
```

i also tried:
`CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=nameOfGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"`

Comment: The problem is that the `ContextMenu` is in a different `VisualTree`.

Comment: You need to post more code than this if you want a meaningful response.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help. I fixed it this way:
 `CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                   AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"`

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer is here: [CommandParameters in ContextMenu in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504533/commandparameters-in-contextmenu-in-wpf)

Another better option imho is to keep "SelectedItem" binded in your ViewModel.

Then you don't need a command parameter anymore, and you can juste use the SelectedItem binded from your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `ContextMenu` is in a different `VisualTree`.

You could use the `Tag` for binding the `Command`. See the following [link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html)