# MenuItem + CommandParameter = null ! Why?

Tags: c#, xaml

I trying to pass a parameter `SelectedItems` to command, but parameter is always null.

```
<sd:SharpTreeView Name="MyTreeView" Margin="10,38,120,10" Root="{Binding Tests}" ShowAlternation="True" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <sd:SharpTreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem
                Header="Copy"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyTreeView, Path=SelectedItems}"
                Command="{Binding CopySelectedTests}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </sd:SharpTreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ListView.View>
...
```

I new in WPF, so for me it is was not helpful to read answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504533/commandparameters-in-contextmenu-in-wpf) and from others questions. It always remain null.

I have tried it not in `ContextMenu` and it works fine, but it is not what I want.

**EDIT 1**

I tried this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=UIElement.(sd:SharpTreeView.SelectedItems), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
```

this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
```

and many other, it is always null.
It only does not null for this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

But it is not what I need.

Comment: The Answer to the question you linked explains the problem and solution.

Comment: @MathewJibin I have read each answer and tried nearly each examples. Nothing work in my case.

Comment: attach a converter to the Binding and debug to see what value you are getting for that command parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved it:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding
    Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems,
    RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}
   }"
```

The important part was to specify `PlacementTarget`.